# MAMP extension won't load

Tags: memcached, mamp

I recently installed MAMP Pro 1.9.5. I followed several tutorials online explaining how to enable **memcached**. I was able to compile correctly with no errors. I added **memcache.so** to my **php.ini** as **extension=memcache.so**. For some reason it does not add the extension. My file is, I assure you, located in the extension_dir of MAMP php 5.3.

On a side-not, it seems when I comment out some extensions in the php.ini it has no affect. Perhaps this might have something to do with it?

Any direction would be GREATLY appreciated. I have wasted many hours finding solutions to this.

Answer (score 1):

After much research and trial and error, I found the solution. The php.ini file I was editing in the MAMP/conf/ directory is in fact **NOT** being used by MAMP. For the record I am using 1.9.5. To edit the php.ini file correctly, you must select **File > Edit Template > PHP 5.x.x php.ini**

This is here in case anyone else needs to know.